# Fullscreen ad on windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

Can I display a full screen ad within my Windows Phone application?
Is there any advice as to how I would achieve this?

Comment: What do you want to do with the screen, show ad for couple of seconds and then navigate to any other page? IMO this will be very discouraging and irritating experience for the user.

Comment: I think, that ad bar discouraging experience for the user more than ad ber, because my app need more space on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you can of course show whatever you like on the screen to the user (within the limitations of the Marketplace, of course).  But if your question is whether there is a framework available to do this, I believe the answer is no.  Currently, the Google ad frameworks that support full screen are only for iOS and Android and the Microsoft ad network doesn't have a full screen option.

You could of course sell ads on your own, but that's quite a hassle.  And you may be able to find a ad network that is selling ads for the web that are roughly the right size, but make sure you check their terms and conditions for allowance on devices (this would also require the use of WebBrowserControl to show these ads, which wouldn't be awful; just a bit of extra setup).